# Div along a percentage of the remaining space with only CSS

Tags: html, css

For example, I have a div absolute that is 30px, what is the best way in css for set the length of a second div the total length of the space left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="display: table; width: 300px; height: 300px; background: lightblue;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 30px; background: lightcoral;">A</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; background: wheat;">B</div>
</div>
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/6AsNK/)